# AWS IoT Resources Access Based on Tags NOT working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iot

We would like to setup some policies so that only device "owners" can access the device shadow ("iot:UpdateThingShadow", "iot:GetThingShadow").

According to this doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html#security_iam_id-based-policy-examples-view-thing-tags) it should be possible to define a device TAG and compare it with the IAM username.
Something like this:

```
        {
            "Sid": "ConnectToThings",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Connect"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:*:*:thing/*"
        }
        {
            "Sid": "ViewThingsIfOwner",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:GetThingShadow",
                "iot:UpdateThingShadow"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:*:*:thing/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {"iot:ResourceTag/Owner": "${aws:username}"}
            }
        }
```

We've tried with the following configuration with no luck:

IOT thing -> "thing00", tagged with "Owner=user00"

IAM user -> "user00" and "user01" with the above defined IAM policy.

Neither "user00" nor "user01" can access the Shadow Service for "thing00". Are we missing something?

Comment: I have an interest in your question. May you perform two variations? 1. Instead of using `iot:ResourceTag/Owner`, use `aws:ResourceTag/Owner` and 2. On global condition keys docs, it is stated "Because you can include multiple tag key-value pairs in a request, the request content could be a multivalued request. In this case, you should consider using the ForAllValues or ForAnyValue set operators" and for me worked (with AppSync actions) when I added `ForAnyValue:StringEquals`.

Comment: After deeper research https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awsiot.html, it seems not possible to attach a condition to the actions "iot:GetThingShadow" and "iot:UpdateThingShadow".
At this point I'm not really sure how can I grant or deny access to my phisical device. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi! Any updates about this? Have the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html), IoT supports tag-based authorization.
If you assign tags to your users or roles, you can grant access only if both the resource and the principal has the same tag attached.

I'd try the following condition after attaching the same tag to the resource and the user, e.g. Owner=UserA.

```
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "aws:ResourceTag/Owner": "${aws:PrincipalTag/Owner}"
     }
}
```

If it works, you can tag your things in groups and assign an attribute (tag) to your users according to your access management policy.

This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/improving-the-management-and-security-of-your-aws-iot-resources-with-tagging/) suggests that UpdateThingsShadow can be used with PrincipalTag.

Comment: Still not working. Sure I'm missing something.
I have this configuration at the moment:
thing00 in a group called things_user00. This group has a tag with TagName owner and value user00
In IAM I have user00 with a tag key owner and value user00. The user has the policy attached with the condition you have suggested.
A python client (acting as user00) is not able to get shadow status
Also a GET request with postman it's not able to get shadow status

Comment: Really weird. Unfortunately, I don't have an IoT environment to experiment. I'd try it out on the console directly. Please also make sure that Python client is using the user's credentials. Good luck.

Comment: Seems to me that an Iot thing can't be tagged. With cli console, the request: aws2 iot list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn "arn:.............:..........:thing/thing00" report an empty list: { "tags": [] } Instead the request made on the things group: ws2 iot list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn "arn:..............:..................:thinggroup/things_user00" reports: { "tags": [ { "Key": "owner", "Value": "user00" } ] } I think the iam policy is not able to get the right tag (despite all the documentation)